# The security protocol cannot secure the outgoing message

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding

I am trying to return a custom fault exception using unity
but I get the following error during Rst\Issue action:

[Service Trace Viewer exceptions][1]

Image:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAxGT.png

1. No signature message parts were specified for messages with the 'http://tempuri.org/IWcfServiceLayer/GetFirstOrder' action.
2. **The security protocol cannot secure the outgoing message**
3. RequestContext aborted

I am using a custmBinding which actually resembles wsHttpBinding.
Here I manually throw an exception in the wcf method, in order to test the behaviour.

When I comment out the throw new exception statement, the service works fine and returns the expected results. But the service cannot handle exceptions currently.
**So why can't the service secure the outgoing message when an exception occurs?**

EDIT (BindingConfig):

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="MyServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <transactionFlow />
      <reliableSession maxPendingChannels="4000" maxRetryCount="20"
        maxTransferWindowSize="4000" ordered="false" />
      <security enableUnsecuredResponse="false" authenticationMode="SecureConversation"
        messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
        <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="SspiNegotiated"
          messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
        <localServiceSettings maxStatefulNegotiations="500" maxPendingSessions="500" />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="100" maxWritePoolSize="50" />
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" allowCookies="true"
        maxBufferSize="2000000" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Comment: Do you use the System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel attribute propery anywhere in your data contract?